# Song from massacre scene, "El Chapo" SE1:EP3

Tags: soundtrack

In SE1:EP3 of El Chapo, does anyone know the name of the song playing in the club during the massacre at the end of the episode?

The show is on Netflix, but here is a link for the scene in a clip on youtube

Comment: How about a link?

Comment: Thank you for warning me about it. Here is the link https://youtu.be/u73pdmeei68?t=2311 It is from youtube because I cannot link from netflix, so the quality isn't great

Answer (score 1):

Is it possibly this song:

Anthony Lazaro + Lazer Owl - Everything is Gonna be Alright (Official Video)

It isn't easy to hear your audio, but I thought I heard the lyric "be alright" and this beat seems to match.

Comment: It might be. The sound isn't really good I know. Thank you. I will try to improve the audio